# AWS Sagemaker Transformer cross account output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am trying to output the batch transformer output to another account s3 bucket(batch_output_path is the destination path) however the KMS encryption key is picked from the source account instead of using the default encryption key which is already set in the (test_bucket). The files are getting placed in the destination bucket but I get below error when I try to download the file.

`AccessDeniedThe ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access.`

How can I enforce S3 bucket to use default encryption kms key of the destination bucket. Below code is from AWS Sagemaker pipeline.py script

```
    batch_output_path= f"s3://test_bucket/folder"

    from sagemaker.transformer import Transformer

    transformer = Transformer(
       model_name=step_create_model.properties.ModelName,
       instance_type="ml.c5.xlarge",
       instance_count=1,
       strategy='MultiRecord',
       assemble_with='Line',
       max_payload=1,
       max_concurrent_transforms=10,
       output_path=batch_output_path,
       sagemaker_session=pipeline_session
    )
```

Comment: Did you try adding output_kms_key attribute to the transformer while creating the transformer.

Comment: Yes  @ArunLokanatha, I did try adding output_kms_key attribute with the destination bucket ARN but Sagemaker pipeline execution failed with a 403: Access Denied error in the transformation step.